# is this javascript code correct?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove a class when clicking on an element with a specific class. I made this javascript and it does work. But is this correct syntax to do it this way Can this be more efficient?

```
// Clear notifications alerts 
$(document).on('click', '.js-clear-notifications', function() {
  $('.AlertNotifications').remove();
});

// clear inbox alerts
$(document).on('click', '.js-clear-inbox', function() {
  $('.AlertInbox').remove();
});
```

Comment: This isn't really on-topic here, you don't have a problem so there's no point asking this question. Specifically, you ask about "efficiency". With such a straightforward snippet, efficiency is a completely negligible factor. You simply attach event handlers, what do you want us to tell you? The answer is a simple "Yes, it's correct".

Comment: I just was wondering if it could be more efficient with an if/ else loop. And I  was not sure if it is allowed to use 2 times:  $(document).on('click',...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code is correct, provided that you load jQuery as well.

Furthermore you have the most efficient solution, where you use a single event handler to handle events that originate on multiple elements.

The alternative would be:

```
$('.js-clear-notifications').on('click', function() {
  $('.AlertNotifications').remove();
});
```

Which attaches as many event handlers as there are elements in the jQuery object. Slightly less efficient, though probably you would never notice except in extreme cases.

Comment: @nuet : Keep in mind that this alternative will only work if the `.js-clear-notifications` exists when this is executed (that element is not created dynamically after that). If that's your case, this solution will be more efficient because you are only listening for clicks on elements of this class, and not on the whole document by using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), like the code you posted in your question.

Comment: @blex In addition, any new `.js-clear-notification` elements will not have a click handler and will need to be re-bound. This adds the pitfall that you must be careful not to attach extra handlers to the elements that already have one. Imo, the original code has the most advantages.

Answer (score -1):

To me a more proper way to do it is something like this:

```
...
$('.js-clear-inbox').on('click', function() {
  $('.AlertInbox').remove();
});  
...
```

I will also suggest to have more specific selectors i.e.

```
$('div .js-clear-inbox')
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Your proposal is actually worse than the original code, see my answer why.

Comment: How is it worse? You assumed functionality and also how do you know that the clicked element has the class the author wants to remove?

Comment: He attached a single handler to click events for all elements. He used the filter parameter to specify the selector. You can't know it's a `div`, so why propose that he includes `div` in his selector? He didn't say too many elements were targeted... So as far as I can see you just invented a problem that isn't there.

Comment: Well i didn't propose to use the 'div', i said its more efficient to use more specific selectors (the author ask wether his solution is efficient). So the 'div' was just an example hence the 'i.e'.

Answer (score -2):

I am editing this in response to the feedback in the comments.

If what you want is to remove all elements with AlertNotifications class, which is what your code does, then what you have is correct.

If what you want is to remove only the class, which is what the text of the post said, you want removeClass, not remove:

```
    $('.js-clear-notifications').on('click',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('AlertNotificitions');
    }
```

Comment: Don't guess desired behavior in answers, the author has stated his code works for him the way he wants it to.

Comment: 'I am trying to remove a class when clicking on an element with a specific class.'.  That is what the OP said, why is it an assumption he wanted it answered?

Comment: fair enough: that's confusing. But since the OP mentioned that the code works, to remove the elements from the DOM really is the desired behavior.

Answer (score -3):

The new way, if you have already defined the variable, the proper way to delete it from the DOM would be:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.remove();
```

But if you are just beginning out, .remove would be your best opinion.

Comment: `.remove()` is not proper native javascript, so your code won't even work. Besides, it seems completely irrelevant to the question.